# Moving Enchantments

Tags: dnd-4e, rituals, weapons

Say you have +2 Frost Mace and you want the enchantment on your dagger instead. Is there a way to move it from one item to another without the Enchant Magic Item ritual?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**, the "[Transfer Enchantment](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/ritual.aspx?id=212)" ritual from the Adventurer's Vault (p199) allows you to do just that.